# PHP MySQLi Prepared Statement: Fetch Not Returning Results for Joins

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I forget where I copied it from (I think a user posted it on php.net) but this function for fetching results of prepared and normal MySQLi statements is not returning any results when used with statements that contain a simple INNER JOIN, at least the one I tried:

```
    function fetch($result){   
    $array = array();           
    if($result instanceof mysqli_stmt){
        $result->store_result();
        $variables = array();
        $data = array();
        $meta = $result->result_metadata();                 
        while($field = $meta->fetch_field()){                   
            $variables[] = &$data[$field->name];
        }               
        call_user_func_array(array($result, 'bind_result'), $variables);
        $i=0;                               
        while($result->fetch()){                                    
            $array[$i] = array();
            foreach($data as $k=>$v)
            $array[$i][$k] = $v;
            $i++;                   
        }               
    }elseif($result instanceof mysqli_result){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        $array[] = $row;
    }           
    return $array;
}
```

I've been trying to use it like so (all these functions are methods of the class $database):

```
    function query($str, $values){                              
    if($stmt=$this->sql->prepare($str)){                    
        $types=$this->castArrayAsString($values); //returns a string of $values's types for bind_params             
        array_unshift($values, $types);         
        call_user_func_array(array(&$stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->makeValuesReferenced($values));                        
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$this->fetch($stmt); //the function I'm having problems with                                                                            
        if(empty($result)){                                     
            $return=true;                   
        }else{
            $return=$result;
        }       
        $stmt->close();         
    }else{
        echo $this->sql->error;
        $return=false;  
    }                       
    return $return;             
}
```

This returns nothing:

```
$list=$database->query("SELECT a.field1, b.field2 FROM table1 AS a INNER JOIN table2 AS b ON a.id_table2=b.id WHERE a.someid=?", array($someid));
```

This works fine:

```
$list=$database->query("SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE someid=?", array($someid));
```

If I print out the meta data from fetching the result, it shows that fields are selected, etc, but still gives no final results in the fetch() func.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

**EDIT HERE IS THE WHOLE CLASS**

```
<?php

class database{

    var $HOST="xx.xx.xx.xxx";   
    var $USER="xxxxxxxxxxx";    
    var $PASS='xxxxxxxxxx';

    var $DATABASE="my_database";

    var $sql;

    function database(){            
        $this->sql=new mysqli($this->HOST, $this->USER, $this->PASS, $this->DATABASE);              
        if($this->sql->connect_errno){
            echo "ERROR - No MySQL connection: ".$mysqli->connect_error;
            exit;
        }                   
    }

    function query($str, $values){                                          
        if($stmt=$this->sql->prepare($str)){                            
            $types=$this->castArrayAsString($values);               
            array_unshift($values, $types);         
            call_user_func_array(array(&$stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->makeValuesReferenced($values));                                
            $stmt->execute();                               
            $result=$this->fetch($stmt);                                                                                        
            if(empty($result)){                                     
                $return=true;                   
            }else{
                $return=$result;
            }                       
            $stmt->close();         
        }else{
            echo $this->sql->error;
            $return=false;  
        }                       
        return $return;             
    }

    function fetch($result){   
        $array = array();           
        if($result instanceof mysqli_stmt){
            $result->store_result();
            $variables = array();
            $data = array();
            $meta = $result->result_metadata();                 
            while($field = $meta->fetch_field()){                   
                $variables[] = &$data[$field->name];
            }               
            call_user_func_array(array($result, 'bind_result'), $variables);
            $i=0;                               
            while($result->fetch()){                                    
                $array[$i] = array();
                foreach($data as $k=>$v)
                $array[$i][$k] = $v;
                $i++;                   
            }               
        }elseif($result instanceof mysqli_result){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            $array[] = $row;
        }           
        return $array;
    }

    function close(){
        $this->sql->close();    
    }

    function castArrayAsString($array){         
        $types="";
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {              
            if(is_numeric($value)){
                if(is_float($value)){
                    $types.="d";
                }else{
                    $types.="i";
                }                   
            }else{
                $types.="s";
            }                        
        }           
        return $types;  
    }

    function makeValuesReferenced($arr){
        $refs=array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value){
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        }
        return $refs;       
    }

}

$database=new database;
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that returns 0 result set is doing an 'inner-join', which means that the source table and the target table must share the same value for the columns being linked against in the query (in this case a.id_table2 and b.id). Chances are you don't have any matching values so you are getting a 0 result set. Try a left outer join.

---

Try the following and see if your results are returned:

```
    "SELECT a.field1, b.field2 FROM table1 AS a INNER JOIN table2 AS b ON a.id_table2=b.id WHERE a.someid = :someId"

    $dbo = new Database();

    $stmt = $dbo->sql->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':someId', $someId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
```

Comment: The values of a.id_table2 and b.id do match, and I've tried an outer join with the same results. To make sure my SQL wasn't wrong I checked it in phpMyAdmin, where it returned the desired results no problem.

Comment: It appears it's not the code, there is an issue with the query itself. Can you post a snippet of your schema?

Comment: Sure,
table1: id (int, autoinc), id_table2 (int), field1 (varchar), field2 (varchar)
table2: id (int, autoinc), field1 (varchar), field2 (varchar)
Again, I tried the exact query I'm having trouble with in an SQL prompt and it does work, but not in the code above, which leads me to believe it is the code. Perhaps something to do with using ON. I'll post the whole class to test with.

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't get that the sql worked from command line but not in code as it is written. Ok so the sql works, just need to figure out why the code isn't working.

Comment: There is A LOT of complex logic around the params being bound within the query, which leads me to believe the param is not being bound correctly. I'm going to do some testing real quick and will post my findings.

Comment: Updated my response with some code, give it a shot and see if it works. The code you are using looks to be outdated (php4 format, although it should still work).

Comment: Ok thanks, the reason for the complexity of fetch() is that it takes the result from the prepared statement and spits out an associative array whose keys match up with the names of the MySQL fields. This is easy to do when NOT using prepared statements, by using the fetch_assoc() command, but when using prepared statements, no such command exists, so one must be created, which fetch() deals with. I suspect when the function encounters a query that contains more complex fields such as 'a.field1' as opposed to just 'field1', it screws up fetching them somehow. That's my guess anyway.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the PDO object, looks like It's not even installed on my version of PHP, so I'll have to install it and take a look, but from the code you posted it looks quite a bit easier for my purposes than what I've been doing, I'll take a look, thanks

Comment: I think you are correct about the complexity the inner join introduces with regards to the params. PDO is far easier to use imo. Let me know your findings.

Comment: Sorry, yes I did actually, by switching to PDO like you suggested. I found it much easier. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. Don't forget to convert others to PDO (or ORM) as well!